# Is there any way to have no google-services.json for some of product flavors?

Tags: android, firebase, android-productflavors

Some of my product flavors work with Firebase and some of them don't. However, if I add **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'** to my dependencies, a google-services.json for each product flavor will be required.
Is there any way to specify, that only some of my product flavors work with Firebase?

My suggestion would be to add a mock google-services.json file for the product flavors that don't use it. Is there any better way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that you could just place an empty google-services.json file in those flavors.

Comment: I get the following error on trying place an empty file there 
`Task :app:processRefactorDebugGoogleServices FAILED
Parsing json file: …/android/app/google-services.json`